# Failed build b/c symbols not found zlib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ssziparchive

I have a problem adding libs for zip extraction to my iPhone app.

I decided to use [SSZipArchive](http://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive#readme). It uses minizip.

After following the instructions:

**1 Add SSZipArchive.h, SSZipArchive.m, and minizip**
[image: added minizip]

**2 Add the libz library to your target**
[image: added libz]

**I still get errors:**
[image]

Symbol(s) not found.

I tried adding -lz to Other Linker Flags and adding lybz.dylib but it didn't help. Please let me know if you know how to get libz to work here.

---

**Solved:** Instead of using a folder, I made a yellow reference group, removed /minizip/ from includes and now everything works.

Comment: how to you make a "yellow reference group" ?

Comment: @jujule Just add New Group. Or if you drag and drop a folder choose "Create groups" instead of "Create folder references."

Answer (score 1):

`unzOpen`, `unzOpenCurrentFile`, and `unzOpenCurrentFilePassword` are functions defined in the minizip library.  The linker is complaining that it can't find those functions, which means they're not getting compiled or linked in properly.

Make sure that `minizip/unzip.c` is included in your project properly and double-check that it's getting compiled and linked.

Comment: I think minizip is linked OK. When I rename minizip folder to something else I get an error that Minizip/unzip.h cannot be found. Is there another test in xcode?

Comment: He said minizip.c, not minizip.h. Not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding minizip.c from the official minizip site. But it's trying to # include <direct.h> and <io.h>. No such file error.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is to make sure

> All the **.c** files under /minizip/ are added to "**Build Phases** >
>   **Compiled Sources**"

[image]

---

For **Cordova** developers who want to use **SSZipArchive** , make sure you don't include the whole /minizip/ folder as source file in plugin.xml ,

```
    <source-file src="src/ios/minizip"/>
```

^^^^^^^^No!

Include them separately as  and :

```
<header-file src="src/ios/minizip/crypt.h" target="crypt.h" />
<source-file src="src/ios/minizip/ioapi.c" target="ioapi.c" />
<header-file src="src/ios/minizip/ioapi.h" target="ioapi.h" />
<source-file src="src/ios/minizip/mztools.c" target="mztools.c" />
<header-file src="src/ios/minizip/mztools.h" target="mztools.h" />
<source-file src="src/ios/minizip/unzip.c" target="unzip.c" />
<header-file src="src/ios/minizip/unzip.h" target="unzip.h" />
<source-file src="src/ios/minizip/zip.c" target="zip.c" />
<header-file src="src/ios/minizip/zip.h" target="zip.h" />
```