# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 SSZipArchive

Tags: ios, xcode, zip, armv7, ssziparchive

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSZipArchive", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   LoginVC.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: So, did you add SSZipArchive.m to the current target?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7) first. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

just solved! I really tried everything, but yeah, it has catched me too now -> CMD+alt+Return, I only have to clean it, and now it works.

Be careful, if you have same problems with SSZipArchive check this:

**- check the prefix.pch: You added some objective-C classes here? -->so just move it into**

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

...cause minizip is compiling together with objective-classes, and thats a problem for minizip, so move it into #ifdef to work clear.

**- clean baby: Just clean like me your project, if you tried many mistakes before [CMD]+[alt]+return - be careful**

**- add SSZipArchive not as reference: Just create your SSZipArchive to first like:**

```
SSZipArchive
    SSZipArchive.h
    SSZipArchive.m
    minizip(folder)
```

..just look also [thisNiceLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956138/failed-build-b-c-symbols-not-found-zlib-solved)..but it can work anyway as referenced folder, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398409/adding-minizip-breaks-objective-c)..both don't worked for me (cause I don't cleaned after experiments ;))..I have created a folder construct like above on finder, and drag drop it into my project (just click "create groups")

..so I hope it helps you.. :)

Comment: That part about the prefix.pch should be engraved with a laser on every Mac produced... thank you! :)